# How can I add an HTML plugin in the `docusaurus.config.js` file for it to appear on every page?

Tags: plugins, comments, docusaurus

I am trying to integrate [CusDis](https://cusdis.com/) (which is a light weight comment system) in a Docusaurus project.

I simply added the following code in one of the pages:

```
<head>
  <script async defer src="https://cusdis.com/js/cusdis.es.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="cusdis"
  data-host="https://cusdis.com"
  data-app-id="*******************************"
  data-page-id="{{ PAGE_ID }}"
  data-page-url="{{ PAGE_URL }}"
  data-page-title="{{ PAGE_TITLE }}"
></div>
```

When I integrate it into single .mdx files, it works just fine. However, I want to figure out a way to integrate it into the `docusaurus.config.js` file itself, so that it gets rendered in each and every page in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some failed attempts, I have finally been able to do this.

STEP 1: Create a new component for Cusdis as `CusdisComments.js` in the *Components* folder.

For reference, my component looks something like this:

```js
import { ReactCusdis } from 'react-cusdis'

export default function CusdisComments (props){
  const appId = process.env.CUSDIS_APP_ID;

  return(
    <div>
      <ReactCusdis
        id = "cusdis-thread"
        attrs={{
          host: "https://cusdis.com",
          appId: appId,
          pageId: props.attrs.pageId,
          pageTitle: props.attrs.pageTitle,
          pageUrl: props.attrs.pageUrl,
          theme: "auto",
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

STEP 2: Go to the docs page you wish to use this component in. Import the component on top like this:

```js
import CusdisComments from '../src/components/CusdisComments';
```

Then, below in the page where you wish to add the component, add the following:

```js
<CusdisComments
  id="cusdis_thread"
  attrs={{
    pageId: frontMatter.id,
    pageTitle: frontMatter.title,
    pageUrl: frontMatter.__resourcePath,
  }} 
/>
```

Also, I have used environment variables to store the Cusdis App Id. So, follow the steps below to set up the environment variables in your Docusaurus Project.

STEP 1: Install the `@docusaurus/plugin-client-redirects` via npm or yarn:

```
npm i @docusaurus/plugin-client-redirects
```

or

```
yarn add @docusaurus/plugin-client-redirects
```

STEP 2: Go to your `docusaurus.config.js` file and under the `module.exports` add the following:

```js
plugins: [
      [
        "docusaurus2-dotenv",
        {
          systemvars: true,
        },
      ],
    ],
```

STEP 3: Add a `.env` file and add your Cusdis App Id, like this:

```
CUSDIS_APP_ID = 123456789 // random id
```

STEP 4: Go to your component and use it as follows:

```js
export default function CusdisComments (props){
  const appId = process.env.CUSDIS_APP_ID;

  return(
    <div>
      <ReactCusdis
        id = "cusdis-thread"
        attrs={{
          host: "https://cusdis.com",
          appId: appId,
          pageId: props.attrs.pageId,
          pageTitle: props.attrs.pageTitle,
          pageUrl: props.attrs.pageUrl,
          theme: "auto",
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Hoping this would help somebody!

Answer (score 2):

I would create a plugin using the `postBuild` lifecycle API (along with possibly the `injectHtmlTags` method as well), you can see an example of the former at [docusaurus-plugin-structured-data](https://github.com/stackql/docusaurus-plugin-structured-data) and the latter at [docusaurus-plugin-hubspot](https://github.com/stackql/docusaurus-plugin-hubspot)